# How get Keyclock permissions in spring boot security context?

Tags: java, spring-boot, keycloak, spring-security-oauth2, keycloak-rest-api

I am trying to protect my springboot microservice with keycloak. I have added the microservice as a confidential client sample-ms. And added a client for frontend to generate the token, All role permissions and scope set properly in keycloak ([as this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3K77Pvv-ouU)), but I didn't get the permission inside authorities.
Here I am getting the roles as authorities (I know because I have configured simple granted authorities). Is there any way to get the permissions in spring security context along with the role?

My springboot security configuration as follows.

**Security config**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(jsr250Enabled = true,prePostEnabled=true)
public class SecurityConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
        SimpleAuthorityMapper grantedAuthorityMapper = new SimpleAuthorityMapper();
        KeycloakAuthenticationProvider keycloakAuthenticationProvider = keycloakAuthenticationProvider();
        keycloakAuthenticationProvider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(grantedAuthorityMapper);
        auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(new SessionRegistryImpl());
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(HttpSessionManager.class)
    protected HttpSessionManager httpSessionManager() {
        return new HttpSessionManager();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/v1/**").authenticated()
                .anyRequest().permitAll();
    }
}
```

**Keyclock config**

```
@Configuration
public class KeycloakConfig {

    @Bean
    public KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver keycloakConfigResolver() {
        return new KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver();
    }
}
```

**application.yaml**

```
keycloak:
  realm: ${KEYCLOAK_REALM}
  auth-server-url: ${KEYCLOAK_AUTH_SERVER_URL}
  ssl-required: external
  resource: ${KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID}
  credentials.secret: ${KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_SECRET}
  use-resource-role-mappings: true



Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = (Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority>)    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities();
```

*here am getting the roles.*

Am tried to access the permission from KeycloakSecurityContext but its getting AuthorizationContext  as null.

```
@Autowired
private HttpServletRequest request;

private KeycloakSecurityContext getKeycloakSecurityContext() {
    return (KeycloakSecurityContext) request.getAttribute(KeycloakSecurityContext.class.getName());
}

KeycloakSecurityContext keycloakSecurityContext = getKeycloakSecurityContext();
AuthorizationContext authContext = keycloakSecurityContext.getAuthorizationContext();//<< null
```

Is there any other way to get the permissions inside the spring security context?

Answer (score 0):

I missed to add some additional filters in configurations

from key clock doc.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
    ...

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean keycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilterRegistrationBean(
            KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter filter) {
        FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean(filter);
        registrationBean.setEnabled(false);
        return registrationBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean keycloakPreAuthActionsFilterRegistrationBean(
            KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter filter) {
        FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean(filter);
        registrationBean.setEnabled(false);
        return registrationBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean keycloakAuthenticatedActionsFilterBean(
            KeycloakAuthenticatedActionsFilter filter) {
        FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean(filter);
        registrationBean.setEnabled(false);
        return registrationBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean keycloakSecurityContextRequestFilterBean(
        KeycloakSecurityContextRequestFilter filter) {
        FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean(filter);
        registrationBean.setEnabled(false);
        return registrationBean;
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(HttpSessionManager.class)
    protected HttpSessionManager httpSessionManager() {
        return new HttpSessionManager();
    }
    ...
}
```

So the complete configuration look likes.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
        SimpleAuthorityMapper grantedAuthorityMapper = new SimpleAuthorityMapper();
        KeycloakAuthenticationProvider keycloakAuthenticationProvider = keycloakAuthenticationProvider();
        keycloakAuthenticationProvider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(grantedAuthorityMapper);
        auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(new SessionRegistryImpl());
    }
    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean keycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilterRegistrationBean(
            KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter filter) {
        FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean(filter);
        registrationBean.setEnabled(false);
        return registrationBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean keycloakPreAuthActionsFilterRegistrationBean(
            KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter filter) {
        FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean(filter);
        registrationBean.setEnabled(false);
        return registrationBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean keycloakAuthenticatedActionsFilterBean(
            KeycloakAuthenticatedActionsFilter filter) {
        FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean(filter);
        registrationBean.setEnabled(false);
        return registrationBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean keycloakSecurityContextRequestFilterBean(
            KeycloakSecurityContextRequestFilter filter) {
        FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean(filter);
        registrationBean.setEnabled(false);
        return registrationBean;
    }
    @Bean
    @Override
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(HttpSessionManager.class)
    protected HttpSessionManager httpSessionManager() {
        return new HttpSessionManager();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/v1/**").authenticated()
                .anyRequest().permitAll();
    }
}
```

now its works.